# Loading fixtures in django unit tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, fixtures

I'm trying to start writing unit tests for django and I'm having some questions about fixtures:

I made a fixture of my whole project db (not certain application) and I want to load it for each test, because it looks like loading only the fixture for certain app won't be enough.

I'd like to have the fixture stored in `/proj_folder/fixtures/proj_fixture.json`.

I've set the `FIXTURE_DIRS = ('/fixtures/',)` in my settings.py.
Then in my testcase I'm trying

```
fixtures = ['proj_fixture.json']
```

but my fixtures don't load.
How can this be solved?
How to add the place for searching fixtures?
In general, is it ok to load the fixture for the whole test_db for each test in each app (if it's quite small)?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can use a relative path? Like `["../../fixtures/proj_fixture.json"]`.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.. Django searches for fixtures only in the proj_folder/app_folder/fixtures

Comment: For those finding this later... here are the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading  -- The specific issue here appears to me to be that the OP provided value for `FIXTURE_DIRS` appears to be an absolute path, when perhaps it was meant to be a relative path from the project root.

Comment: [TestCase fixture loading docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Do you really have a folder `/fixtures/` on your hard disk?

You probably intended to use:

```
FIXTURE_DIRS = ('/path/to/proj_folder/fixtures/',)
```

Comment: I believe by default django looks for app/fixtures because `manage.py loaddata fixture.json` will work without the `FIXTURE_DIRS` variable being set.

Answer (score 118):

I've specified path relative to project root in the TestCase like so:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['/myapp/fixtures/dump.json',]
    ...
```

and it worked without using `FIXTURE_DIRS`

Comment: Don't know why this answer didn't receive more love. It's THE correct answer... You shouldn't have to worry about an absolute fixture path.

Comment: My config may be different but it didn't work until I removed the first `/` character.

Comment: If you're testing locally in one app, it seems to be working to say `dump.json`, because Django automatically looks up the fixtures folder.

Comment: FIXTURE_DIRS is not necessary. os.path.join('/a/b','/c') -> '/c'; so it works when there is no leading slash.

Comment: Related documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading

Answer (score 34):

Good practice is using PROJECT_ROOT variable in your settings.py:

```
import os.path
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
FIXTURE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'fixtures'),)
```

Answer (score 21):

Instead of creating fixures folder and placing fixtures in them (in every app), a better and neater way to handle this would be to put all fixtures in one folder at the project level and load them.

```
from django.core.management import call_command

class TestMachin(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # Load fixtures
        call_command('loaddata', 'fixtures/myfixture', verbosity=0)
```

Invoking  `call_command`  is equivalent to running :

```
 manage.py loaddata /path/to/fixtures
```

Comment: I agree with this, just wanted to point out that the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/initial-data/#where-django-finds-fixture-files) do imply putting them in separate per-app fixtures dirs. Perhaps that is the source of this problem in the first place (it was for me).

Comment: If I have use `setUp` to load my fixtures, do I need to use `tearDown` after?

Comment: Very nice, controlled way of doing things

Answer (score 9):

Saying you have a project named `hello_django` with `api` app.

Following are steps to create fixtures for it:

1. Optional step: create fixture file from database: `python manage.py dumpdata --format=json >  api/fixtures/testdata.json`
2. Create test directory: `api/tests`
3. Create empty file `__init__.py` in `api/tests`
4. Create test file: test_fixtures.py

```py
from django.test import TestCase

class FixturesTestCase(TestCase):
  fixtures = ['api/api/fixtures/testdata.json']
  def test_it(self):
    # implement your test here
```

5. Run the test to load fixtures into the database: `python manage.py test api.tests`

Answer (score 3):

I did this and I didn't have to give a path reference, the fixture file name was enough for me.

```
class SomeTest(TestCase):

    fixtures = ('myfixture.json',)
```

Comment: I'd like to also point out that the `.json` extension is optional too.

Comment: Note that if you aren't using great practices, and you paste the same fixture around with minor tweaks with the same name in different apps, django might load the wrong fixture if you don't list an explicit path to the correct fixture in your test file. Don't assume it will only look in your current app's fixture dir.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, depending on whether you have a fixture, or you have a set of Python code to populate the data.

For fixtures, use `cls.fixtures`, like shown in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2937349/931303) to this question,

```
class MyTestCase(django.test.TestCase):
    fixtures = ['/myapp/fixtures/dump.json',]
```

For Python, use `cls.setUpTestData`:

```
class MyTestCase(django.test.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.create_fixture()  # create_fixture is a custom function
```

`setUpTestData` is called by the `TestCase.setUpClass`.

You can use both, in which case fixtures is loaded first because `setUpTestData` is called after loading the fixtures.

Comment: What kind of code will `create_fuxture` have? I am trying to use fixtures. Even though I specify it correctly, my test is calling db. Why? What did I miss? Is it `create_fixture` logic?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `from django.test import TestCase` and NOT `from unittest import TestCase`. That fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have overridden `setUpClass` method, make sure you call `super().setUpClass()` method as the first line in the method. The code to load fixtures is in TestCase class.

Comment: I know its very basic, but still made the mistake :(