# DJANGO 1.11 - Can't find fixtures

Tags: django, django-fixtures

## Problem

I was trying to use fixtures to populate my database, so I started by reading through the documentation for loaddata and by default, it looks in the fixtures directory inside each app for fixtures. My problem is that when I run `python manage.py loaddata` I'm getting an error, but when I give it the path for teams.yaml it works fine. Do I need to setup something for it to work?

## Documentation

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/#where-django-finds-fixture-files

## Error

```
usage: manage.py loaddata [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                          [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                          [--traceback] [--no-color] [--database DATABASE]
                          [--app APP_LABEL] [--ignorenonexistent] [-e EXCLUDE]
                          fixture [fixture ...]
manage.py loaddata: error: No database fixture specified. Please provide the path of at least one fixture in the command line.
```

## Team App Dir

```
team
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── fixtures
│   └── teams.yaml
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── 0002_auto_20190204_0438.py
│   ├── 0003_remove_team_team_name.py
│   ├── `enter code here`0004_team_team_name.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── 0002_auto_20190204_0438.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── 0003_remove_team_team_name.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── 0004_team_team_name.cpython-36.pyc
│       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
├── models.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── apps.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── models.cpython-36.pyc
├── tests.py
└── views.py
```

## Model

```
from django.db import models

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    team_description = models.TextField(max_length=512, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('create_team', 'Can create a team'), 
        )
```

## Fixture (teams.yaml)

```
- model: team.Team
  pk: 1
  fields:
    team_name: team_name_example
    team_descrition: team_description_example
```

Answer (score 1):

Should you define `FIXTURE_DIRS` in your settings file so django find your fixtures which there are there.

**settings.py**

```
FIXTURE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'fixtures')
]
# statements
```

---

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-FIXTURE_DIRS)

Comment: I'm getting the same error. The link that @bgsuello commented got me what I needed. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The error says: 
`No database fixture specified. Please provide the path of at least one fixture in the command line.`

You need to provide a `fixturename` in `loaddata` command, in your case:

```sh
python manage.py loaddata team
```

It was specified in the doc that by default Django will look into fixtures directory inside your app with the specified `fixturename`. Also the command accepts `./path/to/fixtures/` which overrides the searching of fixtures directory.

Comment: Oh thanks, I misinterpreted the docs. Do you know how to make it search all fixtures inside all apps?

Comment: did you mean, load all fixtures in all apps?

Comment: Yes, I would like to load all fixtures in all apps

Comment: did you try this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225062/load-multiple-fixtures-at-once

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for wasting your time, I'm still a noob at googling. Thank You for your patience.